# Hover not working after changing bootstrap link color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, hyperlink

I tried to override bootstrap link by changing color in this way:

```
.social-icons a {
   color: #fff;
}
```

It worked fine that the color changed. But on hover, nothing happens. What is the problem? What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need also overwrite the a tag with hover event like that:

```
.social-icons a:hover, .social-icons a:visited {
   color: #fff; }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this:

```
.social-icons a:hover, .social-icons a:focus, .social-icons a:active {
   color: #fff !important;
}
```